# Get the prefix for an element in an HTML ordered list

Tags: html, dom, html-lists

Assume the following ordered list in html, using roman numerals

```html
<ol type="I">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li value="1984">big brother</li>
</ol>
```

Which renders as:

```
        I. one
       II. two
      III. three
       IV. four
MCMLXXXIV. big brother
```

Is there a way, given an arbitrary element, to extract from its properties the string used to prefix that element?

For example, given the fourth element, is there something I could do to get the string `IV`?  Or given the last element, getting the string `MCMLXXXIV`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to extract this information from a webpage rendered in the browser of a user?

Comment: I think the question was pretty clear: if I have the HTML above (source code and/or rendered in a browser), how can I get "MCMLXXXIV" from it (e.g. parsing the DOM, using Javascript, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a romanize function. If I am understanding your question correctly.

It would help to have the index of the list item as a value or data-element.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ninjascott/xwozsck4/15/)

```js
$("li").each(function(){
    
    if ($(this).text() === 'big brother') {
     alert(romanize($(this).val()));
    }
 });
 
 function romanize (num) {
    if (isNaN(num))
        return NaN;
    var digits = String(+num).split(""),
        key = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM",
               "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC",
               "","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"],
        roman = "",
        i = 3;
    while (i--)
        roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
    return Array(+digits.join("") + 1).join("M") + roman;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol type="I">
  <li value="1">one</li>
  <li value="2">two</li>
  <li value="3">three</li>
  <li value="4">four</li>
  <li value="1984">big brother</li>
</ol>
```

[As seen here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-roman-numeral-converter)

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I'm trying *not* to do!  Clearly, Chrome or Safari or whatever is doing something like that internally already ... so I'm just trying to grab the value that they generate.